# Why are my Windows 7 System Alerts not coming to the front?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, notifications, alert, window-focus

Ever since I installed Windows 7 Pro SP1 x64 on my Dell XPS M1730, system alerts (for example, the alert you get when installing software that wants to make modifications to your computer) will flash in the taskbar, but will not force their windows in front of other application windows.

The same is true for things like Outlook alerts - notifications for upcoming appointments / tasks etc.

Is this normal, or are there some policy settings or other system modifications I should attempt?